# How to format number "999" as "9.99" using fmt:formatnumber

Tags: java, html, jsp

Currently the order value is shown as xxxx instead of xx.xx, is there any way to change it and display as xx.xx?

I've experimented with substring patterns but it's beyond me sadly, thanks very much in advance

`${order.payment.paymentAuth.auth_amount}` shows the current total

Current result is xxxx (example; 1299) instead of xx.xx (should be 12.99)

Comment: You'll pretty much have to divide by 100. Or to convert to a String with a . inserted somewhere. Neither of which is about formatting a number and therefore cannot be done by formatnumber, or not by formatnumber alone (if you divide by 100, formatnumber will be happy to help.)

Comment: Assuming `order.authAmount` is a variable of type `Double` this might be what you are looking for `<fmt:formatNumber value="${order.authAmount}" pattern="#.00" />`

Comment: Apologies I used the wrong reference at first, it should be "order.payment.paymentAuth.auth_amount" for the value but annoyingly formatting the pattern as above makes it display "xxxx.xx" instead of "xx.xx"

Comment: @kumesana could you give me some guidance on how to convert it? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" pattern="##.##$" value="${Amount}"/>
```

You can use following JSTL tag for your problem.

Comment: Thanks Vinod, sadly it still formats it the same on the page

"Authorised Amount: 1299"